# What story has a man forget a very significant question?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams

I recall reading about a man who has solved some very significant question--The meaning of life, perhaps.  But nobody ever gets to hear this profound discovery because he becomes distracted and the entire revelation is lost to him.

I thought this story might have been part of *Hitchhiker's Guide To the Galaxy* or one of Douglas Adams' books, but I simply cannot find the story.  Please note, I am not thinking of *Deep Thought*.

I apologize if this is too vague, but I just can't remember the details

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone will come and answer right now, but just in case there's some [guidance here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) on asking story identification questions. Feel free to [edit] in any other details you remember ;)

Comment: Apart from the answers already given, there is a story in HHGTG of a small tribe that lives in a wood between two warring factions, and they always get the worst of the fighting despite not being involved. They send an envoy to one of the warlords who explains in great detail why this is the natural order of things. The envoy understands, leaves home, forgets everything on the way and is killed with everyone else in the next skirmish. Don't have the book with me to find the quote, but maybe this jogs someones memories and they can look it up.

Comment: Isn't there a lot in Dirk Gently about forgetting important things and getting distracted?  I haven't read it since it was published so I can't really remember.

Comment: @eshier Yes. Dirk Gently (the novel) featured Samuel Taylor Coleridge, his dream-inspired poem "Kubla Khan", and the so-called Person from Prolock who interrupted him while he was writing it, causing him to forget the rest of the dream.

While it's not regarding a question per se, a lot about OP's question reminds me of this.

Comment: @EikePierstorff That actually fits better than the other answers I think - I had forgotten about that part. You are referencing [Prak](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Prak), which is the name of the person I had forgotten in my answer. I believe the OP is mixing Fenchurch, Prak, and the most powerful man in the universe all in one person, since there are elements of all three in the question.

Comment: I find incredible irony that you've asked a question because you've forgotten the name of the story of a man who forgot a question.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Why did you add the short-stories tag? What part of the question indicates that the OP is looking for a short story?

Comment: @user14111 That the OP is looking for a "story" and that it's a part of a book is what I based my decision on. Looks like I was wrong though :)

Comment: @Goose lol, I didn't even think of that!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you are thinking of the Hitchhikers guide, this could be [Fenchurch](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Fenchurch)

> “And then, one Thursday, nearly two thousand years after one man had been nailed to a tree for saying how great it would be to be nice to people for a change, a girl sitting on her own in a small café in Rickmansworth suddenly realized what it was that had been going wrong all this time, and she finally knew how the world could be made a good and happy place. This time it was right, it would work, and no one would have to get nailed to anything.”

She is promptly destroyed by the Vogons. On the replacement earth, she exists and is romantically linked to Arthur. However, she can never quite place the solution to everything again. (annoyingly I can't find the quote for that)

Comment: This has to be it.  Yeah obviously I didn't remember it all that well, but you pieced it together for me.  Thanks!

Comment: "annoyingly I can't find the quote for that" - That is so wonderfully fitting.

Comment: There was a typographic joke that is always lost...in my original copy, the page ends with "a girl sitting on her" and the next page begins "own in a small cafe".

Comment: @DavidS Speaking of wonderfully fitting, hope you don't get another upvote.

Answer (score 16):

I think French is correct, and this is the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

Fenchurch is probably who you are thinking of, but she wasn't distracted, and didn't necessarily know the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. The Question cannot be known in the same universe as the Answer, as is explained by [Prak](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Prak) (who knows everything in the universe because he took a truth serum). In the latter part of the fourth book, Arthur and Fenchurch seek to find God's last message to his creation, which the pair believe might be what Fenchurch is looking for. Indeed, when they finally reach the location of the words and Fenchurch reads it, she says "yes, that was it", in response to the message. [This](http://asymptotia.com/2006/11/02/gods-final-message/) website suggests an interpretation I hadn't thought of, which is that the message is different for everyone (I don't really buy this intepretation). The message as read by Marvin is

> "We apologize for the inconvenience"  Which isn't really a question or answer.

As for a man getting distracted, you might be conflating Fenchurch with the most powerful man in the universe (from the third book). Since the president of the galaxy is the last person who should actually rule, the person with all the power is someone who doesn't give a crap. This person is unnamed, and lives in a cabin alone on a planet with his cat. He gets distracted very easily. People from the government come to him and asks him questions, which he promptly forgets about. I believe this is what you are remembering.

I can speak with some authority on this subject.

Comment: In the radio series they do not go to a location far away.  Fenchurch is never mentioned in the radio series.

Comment: @Chenmunka you must have listened to a different radio series, since she's a significant part of it. Trust me, I've listened to it about 30 times.

Comment: @Gallifreyan thanks I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Clearly, as there is also no reference to Fenchurch in the published scripts of the radio series which are readily available.

Comment: @Chenmunka bam right [here](http://www.clivebanks.co.uk/THHGTTG/Solong1.htm) Fenchurch is listed. You must have only been looking at the first three arcs. She's just as important in the radio series as the books, maybe even more so.

Comment: @ArthurDent Chermunka is right that Fenchurch is not in the *oriiginal* radio series. The scripts make it clear. Fit the Nineteenth is not part of the original series, it is part of the recent follow-up radio series, which does not predate the books. It's broadcast date is 2005.

Comment: @DJClayworth I was aware that the series didn't entirely predate the books (hence why I said *mostly*), but to be honest, I didn't realize how recent the newer three seasons are. The only reason I quoted the radio series is because I remember it better - i believe that section with God's message is still in the books. To say that "Fenchurch is never mentioned in the radio series" is still very misleading, since they just never got that far in the original broadcast. She is there, but as you mentioned, only in the more recent seasons.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is this scene from Monty Python's the Meaning of Life

Comment: Except that it was accepted as being Hitchhiker's Guide several hours ago?

Comment: @ChrisHayes to be fair, the OP admits a faulty memory. It wouldn't be a stretch to confuse HHGG with Monty Python, and this scene fits the description pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Samuel Taylor Coleridge was interrupted while composing the poem [Kubla Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubla_Khan) in 1797:

> On awakening he appeared to himself to have a distinct
>   recollection of the whole, and taking his pen, ink, and paper,
>   instantly and eagerly wrote down the lines that are here preserved. At
>   this moment he was unfortunately called out by a person on business
>   from Porlock, and detained by him above an hour, and on his return to
>   his room, found, to his no small surprise and mortification, that
>   though he still retained some vague and dim recollection of the
>   general purport of the vision, yet, with the exception of some eight
>   or ten scattered lines and images, all the rest had passed away like
>   the images on the surface of a stream into which a stone has been
>   cast, but, alas! without the after restoration of the latter!
>
> ...
>   Kubla Khan ... was never completed.
>   ...
>
> -- [Wikipedia: person from Porlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_from_Porlock)

There are many stories where a character (or even the real author) is interrupted by someone and forgets something important.

The Coleridge story has led to a ["**person from Porlock**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_from_Porlock) becoming a literary allusion to such cases in general, as well as the above specific case.

Comment: Unless you're suggesting that the OP was thinking of [*another* Douglas Adams story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently%27s_Holistic_Detective_Agency), this doesn't even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: You've not answered the question but provided a comment. This is a story identification question, this user is looking for a particular story and the answer should be in the form of a story suggestion.

Comment: How can I make it clearer that I'm suggesting the OP was thinking of a particular story, the story that Coleridge writes about the writing of the poem "Kubla Khan" ?

Comment: Are you trying to say that OP is thinking about a real-life story of a poet?

Comment: @Chenmunka: Thank you, I edited this answer as you suggested.

Comment: @Chenmunka How can this be better than the Hitchhiker's Guide answer if the HHG answer is the accepted story?

Comment: @DavidCary: It wasn't accepted when I made the comment.

Answer (score 2):

In Michael Chriton's *The Andromeda Strain* there was a biologist working on the problem of a disease that's been brought back to earth aboard a satellite that crashes near a small dessert town, killing almost everyone in the community in a matter of minutes.  The biologist has a flash of insight regarding how the disease works and why only a very young baby and an elderly alcoholic seem to have been immune to its effects.  Before being able to tell any of the other scientists working at the facility, an alarm goes off.  The flashing lights that accompany the alarm trigger an epileptic seizure in the biologist, who then cannot remember the earlier train of thought.

Comment: (a) The OP has already established that the correct answer is something else; (b) The character who has a seizure is a coworker of the POV character who makes the discovery.

Comment: @jwodder What's wrong with adding an additional, relevant answer in case someone who comes looking later is looking for a different, similar storyline?